# Python pandas CustomBusinessDay

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am attempting to filter some time series data without any luck in pandas.. Any tips for what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.. First I am attempting to filter just for the month of July 2013 and then filter the data again for taking hourly averages of the dataset samples.

Ultimately what I am wanting to do is filter the data as described above in addition for Weekdays, OR individual weekdays Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesday, etc. with the CustomBusinessDay function.

I am getting tripped up where the code is commented out for the CustomBusinessDay

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay


time = pd.date_range('6/28/2013', periods=2000, freq='45min')
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=2000), index=time)

print(data)

##weekmask = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri'


df = data.truncate(before='7/1/2013', after='7/31/2013')
df = df.groupby(df.index.hour).mean()
print(df)

##df = CustomBusinessDay(weekmask=weekmask)
##df = pd.bdate_range(start=None, end=None, periods=None, freq='B')
##
##print(df)
```

Comment: First off, your original `data` dataframe doesn't have any july datapoints. `data.index.max()` returns `Timestamp('2013-06-21 19:45:00', freq='15T')`

Comment: Sorry about that.. There should be data being generated for July now... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ultimately what I am wanting to do is filter the data as described
>   above in addition for Weekdays, OR individual weekdays Mondays,
>   Tuesdays, Wednesday, etc. with the CustomBusinessDay function.

Have you considered using `DatetimeIndex.dayofweek`?

> The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6

```
# Exclude Sundays
data.loc[data.index.dayofweek != 6]

# Weekends only
data.loc[data.index.dayofweek.isin([5, 6])]

# Weekdays only
data.loc[~data.index.dayofweek.isin([5, 6])]
```

Also, I think an alternative to `df = df.groupby(df.index.hour).mean()` would be just:

```
df.resample('H').mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... One thing that is odd, is where I am really applying this effort is reading a CSV file of real data.. And the `# Weekends only
data.loc[data.index.dayofweek.isin([5, 6])]` returns a python error. ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

Comment: Do you have any ideas why this would happen on my real data set? Everything else works just fine including it  all on the fake data for the post. Thanks

Comment: Ill have to figure out what this monotonic ValueError is when I am attempting to `data.truncate(before='7/1/2013', after='7/31/2013')` on my real dataset problem

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how I could trouble shoot this error?

Comment: Yeah--I would guess "monotonic increasing or decreasing" would mean you need a sorted index.  Try `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` first.  Give that a try